# jq - Cannot index string with string

Tags: shell, jq

The content is

```
{
  "properties" : {
    "CloudSanityPassed" : [ "true" ],
    "GITCOMMIT" : [ "test1" ],
    "buildNumber" : [ "54" ],
    "jobName" : [ "InveergDB-UI" ]
  },
  "uri" : "http://ergctory:8081/aergergory/api/storage/test-reergerglease-reergpo/cergom/cloergud/waf/ergregBUI/1ergerggregSHOT/ergregerg-34.zip"
}
```

I use this command

```
.[] | ."CloudSanityPassed" | .[]
```

And I get this message

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:8): Cannot index string with string "CloudSanityPassed"
"true"
exit status 5
```

I get, what I want ("true" value), but there is a error in output. Could you explain me, how to avoid it and why does it happen?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to the [jq manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Array/ObjectValueIterator:.%5B%5D), `.[]` gets the values of the object when applied to object.

So you get two objects, one for value of `"properties"` and another for value of `"uri"`:

```
{
  "CloudSanityPassed": [
    "true"
  ],
  "GITCOMMIT": [
    "test1"
  ],
  "buildNumber": [
    "54"
  ],
  "jobName": [
    "InveergDB-UI"
  ]
}
"http://ergctory:8081/aergergory/api/storage/test-reergerglease-reergpo/cergom/cloergud/waf/ergregBUI/1ergerggregSHOT/ergregerg-34.zip"
```

`jq` tries to apply `."CloudSanityPassed"` operator to each object.

Since former object is dictionary (aka hash), you can apply `."CloudSanityPassed"` and get the value `["true"]`, however, latter is a simple string against which you cannot apply `."CloudSanityPassed"`, so `jq` outputs an error at that point.

Maybe the command you want is just `.properties.CloudSanityPassed`.

Answer (score 21):

In my case `jq '[.[] | group_by(.foo)]'` gave the error but
`jq '[.[]] | group_by(.foo)'` worked

Comment: Ugh I assumed `.[]` would return an _array_. But in fact it just separates each object's properties as strings. Thus, wrapping it with another set of parentheses creates an array `[.[]]` DUH!