# How to get value from json using jq?

Tags: jq

I am new to jq and running into a bit of an issue trying to get a value from the json response. I want to get the value of the `PublicIpAddress`

```
{
  "Reservations": [
    {
      "Groups": [],
      "Instances": [
        {
          "AmiLaunchIndex": 0,
          "ImageId": "ami-XXX",
          "InstanceId": "i-XXX",
          "InstanceType": "t2.micro",
          "KeyName": "dev",
          "LaunchTime": "2022-06-04T22:30:04+00:00",
          "Monitoring": {
            "State": "disabled"
          },
          "Placement": {
            "AvailabilityZone": "us-east-1d",
            "GroupName": "",
            "Tenancy": "default"
          },
          "PrivateDnsName": "ip-172-28-99-112.ec2.internal",
          "PrivateIpAddress": "172.28.99.112",
          "ProductCodes": [],
          "PublicDnsName": "ec2-54-11-101-63.compute-1.amazonaws.com",
          "PublicIpAddress": "54.11.101.63",
          "State": {
            "Code": 16,
            "Name": "running"
          },
```

So far i've tried `aws ec2 describe-instances | jq '.[] | {publicIP : .Reservations.Instances[].PublicIpAddress}'` as well as `aws ec2 describe-instances | jq '.[] | {publicIP : .Reservations.Instances.PublicIpAddress}'` but i keep running into `jq: error (at <stdin>:151): Cannot index array with string "Reservations"`

Comment: Have you tried `jq '{publicIP: .Reservations[].Instances[].PublicIpAddress}'` yet?

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Please add that as an answer, i'll accept it.

Comment: `.[] |` only makes sense if your outer item is a list; you're showing something where the outer item is an object.

Comment: [jq - Cannot index string with string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43842672/jq-cannot-index-string-with-string) is caused by someone making the same mistake (using `.[] |` when it isn't appropriate for the form of their data).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - or object :)

Comment: @peak, if the OP wanted to iterate over arbitrary values, yes, but that's not at all the relevant use case. (You're right that I'm speaking in absolutes where there's a corner case wherein the usage is appropriate, but it's a corner case that neither the OP here nor that of the linked question is in).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you want the following:

```
.Reservations[].Instances[] | { publicIp: .PublicIpAddress }
```

Output:

```
{
  "publicIp": "54.11.101.63"
}
```

Note that multiple elements in any of the arrays will produce separate output elements.

Alternative spellings of the same program:

```
.Reservations[].Instances[].PublicIpAddress | { publicIp: . }
.Reservations[] | { publicIp: .Instances[].PublicIpAddress }
{ publicIp: .Reservations[].Instances[].PublicIpAddress }
```

But maybe you are really looking for this?

```
jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[].PublicIpAddress'
```

Which will simply output `54.11.101.63` (one IP address per line, if there are multiple in your input document).